# Find longest word in a sequence of words in Haskell

Tags: haskell

im supposed to write a function that does what the header suggest. However, im struggling with some errors and I cannot find the error in my code. This is what i have so far:

```
import Data.Char

maxWord word = maxWord_h word 0 0

maxWord_h word currVal maxx
    | word == [] = maxOf (currVal maxx)
    | isAlpha (head word) = maxWord_h ((tail word) (currVal + 1) maxx)
    | otherwise = maxWord_h (tail word) 0 (maxOf (currVal maxx))

maxOf a b
    | a > b = a
    | otherwise = b
```

And the error:

```
  Couldn't match expected type `((a0 -> a0) -> a0)
                                  -> (a0 -> a0) -> [Char]'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    The function `tail' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `[Char] -> [Char]' has only one
    In the first argument of `maxord_h', namely
      `((tail ord) (currVal + 1) maxx)'
    In the expression: maxord_h ((tail ord) (currVal + 1) maxx)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point out the errors for me and explain them. Im a beginner with functional programming so be gentle.

Comment: In `maxWord_h`, you call `maxWord_h` in two different ways. Think about it; which one is parenthesized correctly?

Comment: The error message does not match the code given.

Comment: @Code-Guru: it does, it's just missing the letter W.

Comment: If you don't put type signatures on your top-level functions, the compiler won't be able to give you good errors when you make mistakes in those functions. You can get a good sense of what this very common error means by [searching previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22couldn%27t+match+expected+type%22)

Comment: in other words, you want the maximum by comparing length?

Comment: @Code-Guru: Check my first comment. It's a problem of parentheses. To quote: "The function `tail` is applied to three arguments, but its type `[Char] -> [Char]` has only one".

Comment: The reason why the error code and the code above does not match is that my functions have swedish names and i translated them so they would make sense.

Comment: @Rhymoid Thanks! I now realise that maxWord_h ((tail word) (currVal + 1) maxx) really should be maxWord_h (tail word) (currVal + 1) maxx. The easiest errors are often the hardest to spot,

Comment: Unless you've grown accustomed to GHC's error messages. Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around the call to `maxWord_h` so that it gives this: `maxWord_h (tail word) (currVal + 1) maxx`, or move them around the call so that it gives this: `(maxWord_h (tail word) (currVal + 1) maxx)`.

The error is that parentheses introduce sub-expressions, where yours is composed of three sub expressions. In Haskell, a sequence of expressions means the same as it does in Lisp; function application.

In short, you were applying the result of `tail word` as a function with `curVal + 1` and `maxx` as arguments.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers already correct your mistake and prettify your code, 
I would just like to give you more idiomatic ways to solve your problem.

To actually do what the title suggest, you could use

```
import Data.Ord (comparing
import Data.List (maximumBy)

maxWord :: String -> String
maxWord = maximumBy (comparing length) . words
```

To do what your code does, you can write

```
maxLength :: String -> Int
maxLength = maximum . map length . words
```

I trust in your google skills to figure out what the functions I used do.
If not, feel free to ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably specify how a "sequence of words" is represented. Is this a String like `"a sequence of words"`? Or is it a list of words like `["a", "sequence", "of", "words"]`?

You should add a type signature to your functions. This makes it clear to yourself and any other reader what the intent is for each function. It also improves your Haskell compiler's error messages slightly as it assumes that your type signatures are correct, rather than some inconsistent expression, in case of a type mismatch.

The function `maxOf` already exists and is called `max`.

It seems that `currVal` is sometimes used as a number (e.g. `(currVal + 1)`) and sometimes as a function (e.g. `maxOf (currVal maxx)`). Make up your mind about this and declare the true purpose in a type signature. It also seems that when you call `maxWord_h` recursively, you add a set of parentheses that doesn't make sense (pointed at by arrows below):

```
| isAlpha (head word) = maxWord_h (<-- (tail word) (currVal + 1) maxx -->)
```

These parentheses actually break your function.

You should probably try and use pattern matching rather than `head`/`tail`, since this is both idiomatic and safer. For example:

```
maxWord_h [] currVal maxx = max something
maxWord_h (c:rest) currVal maxx =
  if isAlpha c
    then maxWord_h rest (currVal + 1) maxx
    else maxWord_h rest 0 (max something)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the parentheses that was the problem. I will certainly look at your other suggestions as well.